# command not found Angular 2

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I am experiencing a a problem with angular CLI where by every time I close  terminal and start it again. When I try to use terminal I get this error

```
-bash: ng: command not found
```

I have tried to fix path but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

probably angular-cli is not installed properly.I was facing the same issue while ago. try after re-installing.

Comment: I was having problems setting it up on macos so I followed this tutorial docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions, the second option  and the installation was successfully. So am forced every time I want to use ng cli I have to run the commands to change the directory for it to work. Which is kind of annoying.